# get topic from kafka message in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

In our spark-streaming job we read messages in streaming from kafka.

For this, we use the `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` API which returns `JavaPairInputDStreamfrom`.

The messages are read from kafka (from three topics - test1,test2,test3) in the following way:

```
private static final String TOPICS = "test1,test2,test3";
HashSet<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(TOPICS.split(",")));

HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", BROKERS);

JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = 
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                streamingContext,
                String.class,
                String.class,
                StringDecoder.class,
                StringDecoder.class,
                kafkaParams,
                topicsSet
                );
```

We want to handle messages from each topic in a different way, and in order to achieve this we need to know the topic name for each message.

so we do the following:

```
JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new SplitToLinesFunction());
```

and this is the implementation of the `SplitToLinesFunction`:

```
public class SplitToLinesFunction implements Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String> {
    @Override
    public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) 
    {
        System.out.println(tuple2._1);
        return tuple2._2();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `tuple2._1` is null and we assumed that the `tuple2._1` will contain some metadata such as the name of the topic/partition from where the message came from.

However, when we print `tuple2._1`, it's null.

Our question - is there a way to send the topic name in kafka so that in the spark-streaming code, the `tuple2._1` will contain it (and not be null)?

Note that we also tried to get the topic names from the DStream as mentioned in the [spark-streaming kafka-integration tutorial](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html):

But it returns ALL the topics that were sent to the `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream`, and not the specific topic from where the messages (that belong to the current RDD) arrived from.

So it didn't help us to identify the name of the topic from where the messages in the RDD were sent from.

**EDIT**

in response to David's answer - I tried using the `MessageAndMetadata` like this:

```
        Map<TopicAndPartition, Long> topicAndPartition = new HashMap();
        topicAndPartition.put(new TopicAndPartition("test1", 0), 1L);
        topicAndPartition.put(new TopicAndPartition("test2", 0), 1L);
        topicAndPartition.put(new TopicAndPartition("test3", 0), 1L);

        class MessageAndMetadataFunction implements Function<MessageAndMetadata<String, String>, String>
        {

            @Override
            public String call(MessageAndMetadata<String, String> v1)
                    throws Exception {
                // nothing is printed here
                System.out.println("topic = " + v1.topic() + ", partition = " + v1.partition());
                return v1.topic();
            }

        }

        JavaInputDStream<String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(streamingContext, String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, String.class, kafkaParams, topicAndPartition, new MessageAndMetadataFunction());
        messages.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object t) throws Exception {
                JavaRDD<String> rdd = (JavaRDD<String>)t;
                OffsetRange[] offsets = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
                // here all the topics kafka listens to are printed, but that doesn't help
                for (OffsetRange offset : offsets) {
                    System.out.println(offset.topic() + " " + offset.partition() + " " + offset.fromOffset() + " " + offset.untilOffset());
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is that nothing was printed in the `MessageAndMetadataFunction.call` method. what should I fix in order to get the relevant topic for that RDD inside the `MessageAndMetadataFunction.call` method?

Comment: What do you mean "nothing is printed here" ? Not even the "topic = " part, or that part prints but the values are empty.

Comment: If nothing, then you should look in your `YARN` logs, or whatever cluster you are running on. For me, there's log files in `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userLogs/` that capture `stdout` from your executors.

Comment: Sorry -- I know the issue now. It's because your `MessageAndMetadataFunction` has to return both the topic and the message stitched together in a single record. Right now you are returning only the topic, not the message itself. Which is why you get the topic printed out over and over -- because that's what you are returning from `MessageAndMetadataFunction` -- return both, you'll have both.

Comment: Edited my answer to make it more clear

Comment: but how the  `v1.topic()` and `v1.partition` can be returned together? create a `new Tuple2<String, String>(v1.topic(), v1.partition())` and return it?

Comment: You need the message too. You could just return the whole MessageAndMetadata object

Comment: and afer I return the MessageAndMetadata , how can I access it from inside the `VoidFunction.call(Object t)` method?

Comment: I don't know `Java` very well, but my guess would be that `Object t` would be your `MessageAndMetadata` object.

Comment: I returned the `MessageAndMetadata`, but `Object t` is RDD, not `MessageAndMetadata`. so where is it passed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use one of the versions of `createDirectStream` that takes a `messageHandler` function as a parameter. Here's what I do:

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[Array[Byte], Array[Byte], DefaultDecoder, DefaultDecoder, (String, Array[Byte]](
  ssc,
  kafkaParams,
  getPartitionsAndOffsets(topics).map(t => (t._1, t._2._1).toMap,
  (msg: MessageAndMetadata[Array[Byte],Array[Byte]]) => { (msg.topic, msg.message)}
)
```

There's stuff there that doesn't mean anything to you -- the relevant part is

```
(msg: MessageAndMetadata[Array[Byte],Array[Byte]]) => { (msg.topic, msg.message)}
```

If you are not familiar with `Scala`, all the function does is return a `Tuple2` containing `msg.topic` and `msg.message`. Your function needs to return both of these in order for you to use them downstream. You could just return the entire `MessageAndMetadata` object instead, which gives you a couple of other interesting fields. But if you only wanted the `topic` and the `message`, then use the above.

Comment: hey looks like you have an extra brace can you please correct it.

Comment: @David can you please provide a working or detailed example in Scala. As i am confused with these parameters fromOffsets, messageHandler. Thanking You!

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the [Kafka integration guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html), there's an example which extracts the topic from the messages.

The relevant code in Java:

```
 // Hold a reference to the current offset ranges, so it can be used downstream
 final AtomicReference<OffsetRange[]> offsetRanges = new AtomicReference<>();

 directKafkaStream.transformToPair(
   new Function<JavaPairRDD<String, String>, JavaPairRDD<String, String>>() {
     @Override
     public JavaPairRDD<String, String> call(JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd) throws Exception {
       OffsetRange[] offsets = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
       offsetRanges.set(offsets);
       return rdd;
     }
   }
 ).map(
   ...
 ).foreachRDD(
   new Function<JavaPairRDD<String, String>, Void>() {
     @Override
     public Void call(JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd) throws IOException {
       for (OffsetRange o : offsetRanges.get()) {
         System.out.println(
           o.topic() + " " + o.partition() + " " + o.fromOffset() + " " + o.untilOffset()
         );
       }
       ...
       return null;
     }
   }
 );
```

This can probably be collapsed into something more compact which just asks for the topic and nothing else.

Comment: I tried it, it prints all the topics that kafka listens to, instead of only the topic related to the current RDD. e.g. - if I listen to 3 topics - test1,test2,test3 -  and messages arrive from only test1, then this code will print test1,test2,test3 per each RDD. so this code doesn't help me.