# why is the first member of the tuple received from kafka using spark direct stream is null

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

when reading messages from kafka using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream, the v1._1 member of the Tuple2 is null:

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                streamingContext,
                String.class,
                String.class,
                StringDecoder.class,
                StringDecoder.class,
                kafkaParams,
                topicsSet
                ).map(new Function<Tuple2<String,String>, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(Tuple2<String, String> v1)
                            throws Exception {
                        System.out.println(v1._1);
                        return null;
                    }
                });
```

while the _2 member contains the message itself that was passed to kafka.

I have two questions:

1) why is v1._1 null?

2) is there a way to pass the topic name in kafka (the same way the message is put into kafka) so that v1._1 will contain the topic name?

Comment: I already answered this one, since this is a repeat, but I will add that `v1._1` is `null` in this case because it contains the key for the message, which apparently you are not using (hence it is null).

Comment: I looked for the question you answered but couldn't find, could you add a link to it here? and what should be done in the kafka producer side in order to set some value inside the key?

Comment: You accepted my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36771297/4856939

Comment: Your producer needs to create `KeyedMessages`. if you do: `producer.send(List<KeyedMessages>)` it should do the trick.

Comment: thanks. I'll try to send KeyedMessage and update if it works.