# Print RDD out to console in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I write a spark streaming application to receive data from Kafka by using KafkaUtils, and what I want to do is to print out data I received from Kafka. Here is my code(I use spark-submit to execute my spark streaming job):

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet)
messages.print()
```

When I run this, it works pretty fine. If the input is a,b,c in Kafka producer, I can get the result from Spark streaming as below:

```
Time: 1476481700000 ms

-------------------------------------------
(null,a)
(null,b)
(null,c)
```

But if I add one line to count the number of lines, `messages.print()` cannot work. Codes are shown below:

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet)
messages.print()
messages.count().print()
```

I am getting the following result:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1476481800000 ms
-------------------------------------------
4
```

Only count number is getting printed out, and data cannot be printed out.
My question is why `messages.print()` would not be executed after I add `messages.count.print()`.
Another question is what null stands for in the tuple `(null, a)(null, b)(null, c)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with print() and it will print both messages and count like below. Scroll and check your log.

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1476481700000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(null,a)
(null,b)
(null,c)

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1476481800000 ms
-------------------------------------------
4
```

KafkaUtils.createDirectStream method returns DStream of `<Kafka topic, Kafka message>`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770641/get-topic-from-kafka-message-in-spark/36771297#36771297) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778977/why-is-the-first-member-of-the-tuple-received-from-kafka-using-spark-direct-stre) post related to topic is null.

Comment: yes, you are right. They are printed out but I didnt see them before. Thx

Comment: @abaghel Im having similar issue , I only see the Time:1641490510000  as output, rest all as empty.could you please assist.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be working but giving you an alternative.But this approach is only meant for testing or learning. Instead of performing two `actions` , you can achieve the end goal with just single `action`

```
    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet)
    //Cache your RDD before you perform any heavyweight operations. 
    messages.cache()
    val result = messages.collect();
    println(result.size + " size")
    result.foreach { input => println(input) }
```