# Spark streaming for Kafka: How to get the topic name from Kafka consumer DStream?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have set up the Spark-Kafka Consumer in Scala that receives messages from multiple topics:

```
val properties = readProperties()
val streamConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Kafka-Stream")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(streamConf, Seconds(10))

val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" ->  properties.getProperty("broker_connection_str"), 
                      "zookeeper.connect"    ->  properties.getProperty("zookeeper_connection_str"), 
                      "group.id"             ->  properties.getProperty("group_id"), 
                      "auto.offset.reset"    ->  properties.getProperty("offset_reset")
                    )

// Kafka integration with receiver 
val msgStream = KafkaUtils.createStream[Array[Byte], String, DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, Map(properties.getProperty("topic1") -> 1,
                      properties.getProperty("topic2") -> 2,
                      properties.getProperty("topic3") -> 3),
                      StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER).map(_._2)
```

I need to develop corresponding action code for messages (which will be in JSON format) from each topic.

I referred to the following question, but the answer in it didn't help me:

[get topic from Kafka message in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770641/get-topic-from-kafka-message-in-spark)

So, is there any method on the received DStream that can be used to fetch topic name along with the message to determine what action should take place?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what version of `spark` do you use?

Comment: spark-streaming_2.11 ->  1.6.1, spark-streaming-kafka_2.11 -> 1.6.1" and 
kafka_2.11 -> 0.8.2.2

Answer (score 1):

See the code below.

You can get topic name and message by foreachRDD, map operation on DStream.

```
msgStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      val pairRdd = rdd.map(i => (i.topic(), i.value()))
})
```

The code below is an example source of createDirectStream that I am using.

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(configLoader.sparkConfig, Seconds(conf.getInt(Conf.KAFKA_PULL_INTERVAL)))
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> conf.getString(Conf.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS),
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> conf.getString(Conf.KAFKA_CONSUMER_GID),
  "auto.offset.reset" -> conf.getString(Conf.KAFKA_AUTO_OFFSET_RESET),
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)
val topics: Array[String] = conf.getString(Conf.KAFKA_TOPICS).split(",")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it's throwing error on (i.topic(), i.value()): value topic is not a member of String. Are those methods topic() and value() present on elements of rdd there?

Comment: I'm sorry. If you use createStream, you do not know the topic name. If you need a topic name, you must implement it using createDirectStream. With createDirectStream, you can get the topic name through the above code.

Comment: Okay. In the other question that I shared in problem statement, he used the createDirectStream. But I faced issue in passing parameters for it. Can you please show me the working code for createDirectStream implementation, since there are quite a few variations of it?

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll test it on Monday and let you know as I'm home for the weekend. It would be great if you add the import statements and any dependencies that are necessary. Thanks again.

Comment: it's full of errors. Can you please add the import statements as well?

Comment: Can anybody help me out here to run above code? Facing some errors on Conf.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS like properties. I think it is expecting some import statements.